# merging s3 manifest files using jq

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, jq, array-merge

I have multiple s3 manifest files each corresponding to a date for a given date range. I am looking to merge all of the manifest files to generate a single manifest file, thus allowing me to perform a single Redshift copy.

**manifest file 1:**

```
{
    "entries": [
        {
            "url": "DFA/20161001/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_activity_20160930_20161001_050403_294198927.csv.gz"
        }
    ]
}
```

**manifest file 2:**

```
{
    "entries": [
        {
            "url": "DFA/20161002/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_activity_20161001_20161002_054043_294865863.csv.gz"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am looking for an output like:-

```
{
    "entries": [
         {
            "url": "DFA/20161001/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_activity_20160930_20161001_050403_294198927.csv.gz"
         },
         {
            "url": "DFA/20161002/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_activity_20161001_20161002_054043_294865863.csv.gz"
         }
    ]
}
```

I did try

```
jq -s '.[]' "manifest_file1.json" "manifest_file2.json"
```

and other suggestions posted in Stackoverflow but couldn't make it work.

Comment: You realize that your expected output is built up using an object with duplicate keys right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, without resorting to `reduce`:

```
$ jq -n '{entries: [inputs.entries[]]}' manifest_file_{1,2}.json
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "url": "DFA/20161001/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_activity_20160930_20161001_050403_294198927.csv.gz"
    },
    {
      "url": "DFA/20161002/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_activity_20161001_20161002_054043_294865863.csv.gz"
    }
 ]
}
```

Note that `inputs` was introduced in jq version 1.5.  If your jq does not have `inputs`, you can use `jq -s` as follows:

```
$ jq -s '{entries: [.[].entries[]]}' manifest_file_{1,2}.json
```

Answer (score 0):

So if by "merge" you mean to combine the `"entries"` arrays into a single array by concatenating them, you could do this:

```
$ jq 'reduce inputs as $i (.; .entries += $i.entries)' manifest_file{1,2}.json
```

Which yields:

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "url": "DFA/20161001/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_activity_20160930_20161001_050403_294198927.csv.gz"
    },
    {
      "url": "DFA/20161002/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_activity_20161001_20161002_054043_294865863.csv.gz"
    }
  ]
}
```